# How can I disable the beep when changing the volume?

Tags: windows-xp, audio

On Windows XP, whenever I raise or lower the volume via the system tray, the PC makes a beep when I let go of the mouse. How do I disable this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our friends over at the How-To-Geek have a [nice guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/turn-off-the-annoying-windows-xp-system-beeps/) to do just this.

> Open up Control Panel and find the
>   Sounds and Audio Devices panel, choose
>   the Sounds tab and then find “Default
>   Beep” in the list.
>
> [image]
>
> Change the sound drop-down on the
>   bottom to “None” and then click Apply.
>   This should disable the volume control
>   beep.
>
> You’ll want to also change Critical
>   Stop to “None” as well, and should
>   probably also turn off some of the
>   other items.
>
> You can also use TweakUI to get rid of
>   some of the beeps, but if you follow
>   the items on this page you shouldn’t
>   need that.

Answer (score 0):

If you still get a speaker beep, disable the beep.sys hardware driver (really!):

[This link](http://www.softech.com/products/expertcad/tips/td_ExpertCADTip_DisablingTheSystemBeep.pdf) goes to a PDF with good graphics that describes how to do it.

Comment: link seems to be dead. :(