# Windows 11 volume control notification sound settings

Tags: audio

Windows 11 Volume Control button makes ding sound every time I turn the volume up or down.

How to turn off the notification sound?

Comment: It is there to tell you how loud you set it. Without you would not know. Suggest you keep it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable the beep when changing the volume?](https://superuser.com/questions/45365/how-can-i-disable-the-beep-when-changing-the-volume)

Answer (score 0):

Click on Start menu and go to control panel and select sound settings icon. (step 1, 2)

On sound setting choose third tab from the top "sounds".(step 3)

under the windows tab keep scrolling down to "notification" and select it by clicking on notification. (step 4)

Now you are going to see another drop down menu on the same window "Sounds" the default selection is "windows notify system generic"

change it to "none" and you  won't have any sound (step 5)

follow the steps in pictures for more clarification.

Thanks
Khan

[all steps in one picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io3pl.png)

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Uyfa.png)

[step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvevA.png)

[step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am8jQ.png)

[step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqxTr.png)

[step 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcXGM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the directions on the answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/351136/1840013) but instead of selecting "Default Beep" select "Notification".

Comment: Pleaee post the essentials here. Link only answers get deleted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1213385)